# How to start AUAudioFilePlayer in the middle of a track but loop to the beginning?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

In iOS I'm using the `AUAudioFilePlayer` and I'm trying to do a 10 second lead in before looping the entire audio track.  I've set the `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` as below to start on a non-zero frame (details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1786/_index.html)

```
ScheduledAudioFileRegion playRegion;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
playRegion.mCompletionProc = NULL;
playRegion.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
playRegion.mAudioFile = audioFileId;
playRegion.mLoopCount = UInt32(-1);
playRegion.mStartFrame = startFrame;
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = UInt32(-1);  // i.e. all of it
_(AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
                       kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion,
                       kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                       0,
                       &playRegion,
                       sizeof(playRegion)),
  @"Error setting Audio File Region on the FilePlayer AU");
```

The problem is that when it loops it starts again at `startFrame`.  Any ideas how I get it start at the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to do two schedules.  `mTimeStamp.mSampleTime` is how long relative to the scheduled start time to wait until playing:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
// PRE-AMBLE
/////////////////////////////////////////

// Tell it to play the whole file with optional looping...
// more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1786/_index.html
ScheduledAudioFileRegion playRegion;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;  // PLAY IMMEDIATELY...
playRegion.mCompletionProc = NULL;
playRegion.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
playRegion.mAudioFile = audioFileId;
playRegion.mLoopCount = 0;
playRegion.mStartFrame = startFrame;   // ...FROM REQUEST START FRAME
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = UInt32(-1);  // i.e. all of it
_(AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
                       kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion,
                       kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                       0,
                       &playRegion,
                       sizeof(playRegion)),
  @"Error setting Audio File Region on the FilePlayer AU");


/////////////////////////////////////////
// LOOP
/////////////////////////////////////////

playRegion.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = lengthInFrames - startFrame; // WAIT UNTIL PREAMBLE IS DONE...
playRegion.mCompletionProc = NULL;
playRegion.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
playRegion.mAudioFile = audioFileId;
playRegion.mLoopCount = UInt32(-1);
playRegion.mStartFrame = 0;         // ...THEN PLAY FROM THE BEGINNING
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = UInt32(-1);  // i.e. all of it
_(AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
                       kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion,
                       kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                       0,
                       &playRegion,
                       sizeof(playRegion)),
  @"Error setting Audio File Region on the FilePlayer AU");
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? I set up the first `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` and right after I set up the second one. But I've to wait `lengthInFrames - startFrame` until to hear sound. It's like the first `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` is useless. Did I miss something? Or did you mean to use 2 different `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` ?

Comment: It's been a while but I believe AudioUnitSetProperty does a memcpy so it shouldn't matter if they are the same variable.  Did you set `mSampleTime = 0` on the first call?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured it out by using 2 different `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` one called `playRegion` and an other `playRegionLoop`. This way the second one will start when the first one is finished.
The `mSampleTime = 0` is set on the first call but I didn't manage to use only one `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` like you did in your code.